# Sqlite dynamic column names

Tags: python, sqlite

I have the following Sqlite setup trying to update `Tablename` table with  `Keys` items as both column name and value 
The problem is that i want to add all `items` into single record where `Name` doesn't change but `Items` change to take all `Items` in `Keys`

My code will do this over for loop but with multiple records , All i want is a single records with all `Items`

```
Keys=['a','b',etc]
Tablename='Asfoor'
Name='Deek'
    for item in keys:
        data=[Name,Item]
        cur.executemany("INSERT INTO "+Tablename+" (Name,"+Item+") VALUES(?,?)",(data,))
```

Complete code :

```
import sqlite3
import sys
tablename='asfoor'
table_data=['Name','a','b','c']

try:
    con = sqlite3.connect('dbtrials.db')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+tablename+"")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE "+tablename+" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,Name TEXT, "+table_data[1]+" TEXT, "+table_data[2]+" TEXT, "+table_data[3]+" TEXT )")

    keys=['a','b','c']

    name='deek'
    for item in keys:
        data=[name,item]
        cur.executemany("INSERT INTO "+tablename+" (name,"+item+") VALUES(?,?)",(data,))
    cursor = cur.execute("select * from "+tablename+" ")
    for row in cursor  :
          print(row)


except sqlite3.Error as e:

    print ("Error %s:" % e.args[0])
    sys.exit(1)

finally:

    if con:
        con.close()
```

Comment: It depends on your SQL schema. Is your database schema even initialize? Have you look at using `pandas` library or do you want to achieve this using `sqlite` module only?

Comment: I want it in Sqlite

Comment: You didn't answer my first question. What is your database schema? Is it even initialized?

Comment: I'm new to python and Sqlite .So i'm not getting what you mean by your questions .

Comment: Database schema has nothing to do with python. Database schema in this context has to do with a sql database, i.e. the sqlite database. Have you used sql before? If so, you should at least know how to create a table and not only insert into a table.

Comment: I updated the question with complete code .